# Does googlebot recognize an HTML <title> tag altered by javascript ?

Tags: javascript, ajax, googlebot

I have a search engine on my website and it works via ajax. I want to have a specific `<title>` for each search attempt. To achive that I have to alter  every time after I recieve a response from ajax.

Do you have any idea if googlebot will see this altered  and use it to index my webpage?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

> Do you have any idea if googlebot will see this altered and use it to index my webpage?

Most likely not.

You should change the title on server side.

Answer (score 2):

Google bot does something similar to opening the page URL using notepad. It will see the JavaScript code as a plain text, which tries to change the title; but it will **not** see the result of the script execution of course.

**EDIT**:

Ajax enabled web pages are crawled using the same principle, unless they follow the techniques for Ajax-enabled web sites, as suggested by google:
[AJAX crawling: Guide for webmasters and developers](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=174992)

Comment: No, actually Google DOES execute JavaScript on pages it indexes in attempt to detect hiding text behind full-page banners and other things, trying to index pages in condition that visitors will actually see. As far as I remember it even didn't index text that was of same color with background. It was about 2 or 3 years ago though, not sure if it's still so.

Comment: Please look at Google webmaster guidelines in order to understand how it handles JavaScipt.

Answer (score 0):

Well, google added many features to its search engine over past years, and probably it will be able to see the changes. But how do you imagine a client should reach a page which address doesn't change, but content does after few clicks? You must combine AJAX with normal separate pages; this will also add compatibility for clients that have JavaScript disabled. E.g. have all pages redirect to the one working with AJAX if JavaScript is enabled and user-agent string doesn't match `*bot*`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, Google will not index any dynamic content from your page.

As Slava said, Google added many features to its search engine over past years, and probably it will be able to see the changes. But even if Google does eventually start indexing dynamically changed content, I think it is still uninteresting from a search engine optimization standpoint that those content will not be indexed as quickly as the others served from server.

It's important to know what you're getting and what you're losing. Yes, you may be adding functionality to your page easily and enhancing the user experience, but if you don't get the data indexed, you lose all that juicy keywordy goodness. :)